# My pipeline should read the files which have ". parquet" and also the parquet files without ". parquet " extension?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, parquet, azure-synapse

My pipeline should read the files which have ". parquet" and also the parquet files without ". parquet " extension? How can I achive both in my Synapse pipeline?

Comment: Can you please share more details on what is your pipeline trying to do? Is it a copy activity?

Comment: Yes , copy activity , from the source side it should read the parquet files.But It's only reading the files without " . parquet "extension and its getting failed for files which have ". parquet" extension. the copy activity should read both the cases

Comment: ok, can you please share the details of your source linked service and if possible, source data set ?

Comment: can I have ur email id or any of the contact details so that I can connect.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Wild card paths to copy parquet files. When you use Wild card paths, you are violating the rule below.

**All files matching the wildcard path will be processed.** Overrides the folder and file path set in the dataset.

Some files have .parquet extension and some files don’t have .parquet extension. This is not allowed.

You need to have all files either with .parquet extension or without .parquet extension.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet#source-properties

Comment: No am using Filepath in dataset . Am not using wildcard path

Comment: Then how will it select multiple files ? You need to use wild card path. Also you need to make sure all files should have same extension.

Comment: I have used a split function to read multiple files separated by comma,